# How to solve an LCP (linear complementarity problem) in python?

Tags: python

Is there a good library to numericly solve an [LCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complementarity_problem) in python ?

**Edit:** I need a working python code example because most libraries seem to only solve quadratic problems and i have problems converting an LCP into a QP.

Comment: Genuine question: what problems do you have converting the LCP to a QP? The Wikipedia article makes it sound as if this were trivial, by simply applying the formula given there (provided that M is positive definite). But since I’ve never worked with either problems, maybe I overlooked something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For quadratic programming with Python, I use the [`qp`](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#quadratic-programming)-solver from [`cvxopt`](http://cvxopt.org/) ([source](https://github.com/cvxopt/cvxopt/)). Using this, it is straightforward to translate the LCP problem into a QP problem (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complementarity_problem)). Example:

```
from cvxopt import matrix, spmatrix
from cvxopt.blas import gemv
from cvxopt.solvers import qp

def append_matrix_at_bottom(A, B):
    l = []
    for x in xrange(A.size[1]):
        for i in xrange(A.size[0]):
            l.append(A[i+x*A.size[0]])
        for i in xrange(B.size[0]):
            l.append(B[i+x*B.size[0]])
    return matrix(l,(A.size[0]+B.size[0],A.size[1]))

M = matrix([[ 4.0, 6,   -4,    1.0 ],
            [ 6,   1,    1.0   2.0 ],
            [-4,   1.0,  2.5, -2.0 ],
            [ 1.0, 2.0, -2.0,  1.0 ]])
q = matrix([12, -10, -7.0, 3])

I = spmatrix(1.0, range(M.size[0]), range(M.size[1]))
G = append_matrix_at_bottom(-M, -I)   # inequality constraint G z <= h
h = matrix([x for x in q] + [0.0 for _x in range(M.size[0])])

sol = qp(2.0 * M, q, G, h)      # find z, w, so that w = M z + q
if sol['status'] == 'optimal':
    z = sol['x']
    w = matrix(q)
    gemv(M, z, w, alpha=1.0, beta=1.0)   # w = M z + q
    print(z)
    print(w)
else:
    print('failed')
```

Please note:

- the code is totally untested, please check carefully;
- there surely are better solution techniques than transforming LCP into QP.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the scikit [OpenOpt](http://openopt.org/Welcome). It has an example of doing [quadratic programming](http://projects.scipy.org/scikits/browser/trunk/openopt/scikits/openopt/examples/qp_1.py) and I believe that it goes beyond SciPy's optimization routines. NumPy is required to use OpenOpt. I believe that the wikipedia page that you pointed us to for LCP describes how to solve a LCP by QP.

Answer (score 3):

The best algorithm for solving MCPs (mixed nonlinear complementarity problems, more general than LCP) is the PATH solver: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ferris/path.html

The PATH solver is available in matlab and GAMS. Both are coming with a python API. I have chosen to use GAMS because there is a free version. So here is a step by step solution to solve an LCP with the python API of GAMS. I used python 3.6:

1. Download and install GAMS: https://www.gams.com/download/
2. Install the API to python like here: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/API_PY_TUTORIAL.html
   I used conda, changed the directory to were the apifiles of python 3.6 were and entered

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```
3. Create a .gms-file (GAMS file) lcp_for_py.gms containing:

   ```
   sets i;

   alias(i,j);

   parameters m(i,i),b(i);

   $gdxin lcp_input
   $load i m b
   $gdxin

   positive variables z(i);

   equations Linear(i);

   Linear(i).. sum(j,m(i,j)*z(j)) + b(i) =g= 0;

   model lcp linear complementarity problem/Linear.z/;

   options mcp = path;

   solve lcp using mcp;

   display z.L;
   ```
4. Your python code is like this:

   ```
   import gams

   #Set working directory, GamsWorkspace and the Database
   worDir = "<THE PATH WHERE YOU STORED YOUR .GMS-FILE>" #"C:\documents\gams\"
   ws=gams.GamsWorkspace(working_directory=worDir)
   db=ws.add_database(database_name="lcp_input")

   #Set the matrix and the vector of the LCP as lists
   matrix = [[1,1],[2,1]]
   vector = [0,-2]

   #Create the Gams Set
   index = []
   for k in range(0,len(matrix)):
   index.append("i"+str(k+1))

   i = db.add_set("i",1,"number of decision variables")
   for k in index:
       i.add_record(k)

   #Create a Gams Parameter named m and add records
   m = db.add_parameter_dc("m", [i,i], "matrix of the lcp")
   for k in range(0,len(matrix)):
       for l in range(0,len(matrix[0])):
           m.add_record([index[k],index[l]]).value = matrix[k][l]

   #Create a Gams Parameter named b and add records
   b = db.add_parameter_dc("b",[i],"bias of quadratics")
   for k in range(0, len(vector)):
       b.add_record(index[k]).value = vector[k]

   #run the GamsJob using the Gams File and the database
   lcp = ws.add_job_from_file("lcp_for_py.gms")
   lcp.run(databases = db)

   #Save the solution as a list an print it
   z = []
   for rec in lcp.out_db["z"]:
       z.append(rec.level)

   print(z)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

OpenOpt has a free LCP solver written in Python + NumPy see http://openopt.org/LCP